# CFileDialog - Where is SetCurrentDirectory called

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have an old instrument controller and UI, written in C++ using the MFC wrapper libraries back in 2005. I compiled and packaged it into an installer with Visual Studio 2005, and I've been using the same executable on various systems since then.

Recently, I wanted to make a few adjustments so I built a new project with my current VS (2012). I compiled and tested the program, before making any code changes, and was surprised to discover a change in MFC functionality, for a simple CFileDialog modal Save-As box.

My original code:

```
char strFilter[] = { "TIC Data (*.tic)|*.tic|All Files (*.*)|*.*||" };
CFileDialog fileDlg(FALSE, ".tic", NULL, 0, strFilter);
if( fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK ) {
    m_strFileName = fileDlg.GetFileName(); // m_strFileName is CString
    if (m_pFileOut->Open(m_strFileName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate | CFile::modeWrite)) {
        ... stuff ...
    }
}
```

This worked fine in the VS2005 build. When I recompiled it with VS2012, I found that my `CFile *m_pFileOut` would create/open a file with a filename matching that of the string `m_strFileName` as returned by `::GetFileName` - as it should; but the file is created in the program's current working directory, instead of the directory supplied by the user via the CFileDialog.

The obvious solution is to use `::GetPathName` instead of `::GetFileName`. I believe I used GetFileName back in '05 because our paths could get quite long, and (for display-purposes on the GUI) I preferred the brevity of filename only.

Finally to the point... How did my original code ever work? `::GetFileName` returns only the filename, with the [fqpn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) stripped.

**Question 1:**

I can only guess that, somewhere in the MFC class, `CFileDialog` must have set the application's current working directory based on user interaction with the modal Save-As box. Is this right? Can anyone confirm that this **was** how it worked in the old framework?

This seems like a terrible design! I can only imagine how many hidden bugs this must have created. Perhaps that's why they changed it.

In the VS2012 build, I can make it work (without using GetPathName) by adding `SetCurrentDirectory(fileDlg.GetFolderPath())`, like so:

```
m_strFileName = fileDlg.GetFileName();
SetCurrentDirectory(fileDlg.GetFolderPath());
if (m_pFileOut->Open(...)) { etc. }
```

**Question 2:**

Where is the documentation? I can find neither the document which describes how/where/when (and most importantly) why, the old CFileDialog class calls `SetCurrentDirectory`, nor can I find the document which describes the change in this behavior, for the newer MFC classes.

Thanks

Comment: I believe I observed the same behavior (Save As dialog updates the current working directory as the user navigates) in a Visual Studio 2008 project. The obvious solution is: Do not ever rely on the current working directory. It is set per-process and any thread can change it at any given time. Just use fully-qualified path names. For display purposes you can use `GetFileName()` instead.

Comment: The CFileDialog implementation has changed over the years, from GetOpenFileName() before Vista to IFileDialog today.  At least the former would change the program's working directory as the user navigated directories in the dialog, meant to be helpful but an enormous source of bugs.  You are supposed to use OFN_NOCHANGEDIR to avoid this, easy to overlook.